# How to customize Alfresco Activiti Workflow form?

Tags: workflow, alfresco, activiti

I want to customize alfresco activiti workflow form in a way that once workflow is triggered, user/approver can see customized details for workflow instead of standard alfresco share workflow details page?

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got a way to do this. Just update share-config-custom.xml under tomcat\shared\classes\alfresco\web-extension by adding  entry with condition as workflow name as below & do not forget to add prefix "activiti$" to workflow name.

[image]